# Loader image not showing up when canvas rotating and resizing operation is going on selected file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I have created sample code here http://jsfiddle.net/kamlesh_bhure/YpejU/ where i am rotating image and resizing it as per max height and width.

Before starting this process I am showing mask with loading image and hiding it after completing it. But I am not able to see this loader on mobile device or on desktop browser even though I used large image.

Also I want to show loading image till browser complete its rendering of processed image.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- HTML Code -->
<div id="mask" class="newLoaderMask">
    <img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading1.gif" width="200" id="loader" />
</div>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="takePictureField" />
<div class="captureInsuPanel">
    <img id="yourimage" class="imgWeightHght" width="500" />
</div>
<canvas id="hidden_canvas_old"></canvas>
<canvas id="hidden_canvas_new"></canvas>
<style>
#yourimage {
    width:100%;
}
.imgWeightHght {
    height: 290px !important;
    width: 220px !important;
}
.captureInsuPanel img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.newLoaderMask {
    display: none;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>

<script>
//Js Code 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#takePictureField").on("change", gotPic);
});

function gotPic(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length == 1 && event.target.files[0].type.indexOf("image/") == 0) {
        var image = event.target.files[0];
        $("#yourimage").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(image));
        drawRotatedImage(image, 90, 800, 1000);
    }
}

function drawRotatedImage(image, angle, max_width, max_height) {
    //show loading mask
    $('#mask').show();
    var fileLoader = new FileReader(),
        imageObj = new Image();

    if (image.type.indexOf("image/") == 0) {
        fileLoader.readAsDataURL(image);
    } else {
        alert('File is not an image');
    }
    fileLoader.onload = function () {
        var data = this.result;
        imageObj.src = data;
    };

    fileLoader.onabort = function () {
        alert("The upload was aborted.");
    };

    fileLoader.onerror = function () {
        alert("An error occured while reading the file.");
    };


    // set up the images onload function which clears the hidden canvas context, 
    // draws the new image then gets the blob data from it
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        var imgWidth = this.width;
        var imgHeight = this.height;
        rotateAndResize(this, imgWidth, imgHeight);

    };

    function rotateAndResize(image, imgWidth, imgHeight) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("hidden_canvas_old"),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var widthHalf = imgWidth / 2,
            heightHalf = imgHeight / 2;

        canvas.width = imgWidth;
        canvas.height = imgWidth;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.drawImage(image, -widthHalf, -widthHalf);

        ctx.restore();

        var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("hidden_canvas_new"),
            tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

        tempCanvas.width = imgHeight;
        tempCanvas.height = imgWidth;
        /*
         * Crop rotated image from old canvas to remove white space 
         * So that canvas will have only image content without extra padding
         */
        tCtx.drawImage(canvas, canvas.width - imgHeight, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth, 0, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth);
        tCtx.restore();

        /**
         * Resizing Rotated image
         */
        // calculate the width and height, constraining the proportions
        if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
            if (imgWidth > max_width) {
                imgHeight = Math.round(imgHeight *= max_width / imgWidth);
                imgWidth = max_width;
            }
        } else {
            if (imgWidth > max_height) {
                imgWidth = Math.round(imgWidth *= max_height / imgHeight);
                imgHeight = max_height;
            }
        }
        var tempCanvasTemp = tempCanvas;
        tempCanvas.remove();
        canvas.remove();

        var tempCanvas1 = document.createElement("canvas"),
            tCtx1 = tempCanvas1.getContext("2d");

        tempCanvas1.id = 'hidden_canvas_new';
        //tempCanvas1.style.display = 'none';
        tempCanvas1.width = imgHeight;
        tempCanvas1.height = imgWidth;

        tCtx1.drawImage(tempCanvasTemp, 0, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth);
        tCtx1.restore();

        document.body.appendChild(tempCanvas1);

        $("#yourimage").attr("src", tempCanvas1.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    }
    //hide loading mask
    $('#mask').hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should copy your code here. StackOverflow prevents you from just having a jsFiddle only for a reason

Comment: @Zeaklous I have edited Question with same code for more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding your loading div `#mask` in `drawRotatedImage` function but you should hide it in `rotateAndResize` function where you are drawing your picture to canvas.

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#takePictureField").on("change", gotPic);
});

function gotPic(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length == 1 && event.target.files[0].type.indexOf("image/") == 0) {
        var image = event.target.files[0];
        $("#yourimage").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(image));
        drawRotatedImage(image, 90, 800, 1000);
    }
}

function drawRotatedImage(image, angle, max_width, max_height) {
    $('#mask').show();
    var fileLoader = new FileReader(),
        imageObj = new Image();

    if (image.type.indexOf("image/") == 0) {
        fileLoader.readAsDataURL(image);
    } else {
        alert('File is not an image');
    }
    fileLoader.onload = function () {
        var data = this.result;
        imageObj.src = data;
    };

    fileLoader.onabort = function () {
        alert("The upload was aborted.");
    };

    fileLoader.onerror = function () {
        alert("An error occured while reading the file.");
    };


    // set up the images onload function which clears the hidden canvas context, 
    // draws the new image then gets the blob data from it
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        var imgWidth = this.width;
        var imgHeight = this.height;
        rotateAndResize(this, imgWidth, imgHeight);

    };

    function rotateAndResize(image, imgWidth, imgHeight) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("hidden_canvas_old"),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var widthHalf = imgWidth / 2,
            heightHalf = imgHeight / 2;

        canvas.width = imgWidth;
        canvas.height = imgWidth;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.drawImage(image, -widthHalf, -widthHalf);

        ctx.restore();

        var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("hidden_canvas_new"),
            tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

        tempCanvas.width = imgHeight;
        tempCanvas.height = imgWidth;
        /*
         * Crop rotated image from old canvas to remove white space 
         * So that canvas will have only image content without extra padding
         */
        tCtx.drawImage(canvas, canvas.width - imgHeight, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth, 0, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth);
        tCtx.restore();

        /**
         * Resizing Rotated image
         */
        // calculate the width and height, constraining the proportions
        if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
            if (imgWidth > max_width) {
                imgHeight = Math.round(imgHeight *= max_width / imgWidth);
                imgWidth = max_width;
            }
        } else {
            if (imgWidth > max_height) {
                imgWidth = Math.round(imgWidth *= max_height / imgHeight);
                imgHeight = max_height;
            }
        }
        var tempCanvasTemp = tempCanvas;
        tempCanvas.remove();
        canvas.remove();

        var tempCanvas1 = document.createElement("canvas"),
            tCtx1 = tempCanvas1.getContext("2d");

        tempCanvas1.id = 'hidden_canvas_new';
        //tempCanvas1.style.display = 'none';
        tempCanvas1.width = imgHeight;
        tempCanvas1.height = imgWidth;

        tCtx1.drawImage(tempCanvasTemp, 0, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth);
        tCtx1.restore();

        document.body.appendChild(tempCanvas1);

        $("#yourimage").attr("src", tempCanvas1.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
         $('#mask').hide();
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YpejU/11/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** While testing fiddle found out one more issue, if we try to upload image second time second canvas in not updating with new image. Hope you need to work on this.

Comment: Yes i know there is issue in sample code. I resolved it in my main code. thanks buddy for pointing out my silly mistake.